# Conditional Probability/Bayes' Theorem Question

Tags: probability

> A child is playing with wooden blocks among which there are 8 blue, 5
>   yellow, and 2 red. The blocks are identical except for their color. A
>   child arranges all of them randomly in a straight line. What is the
>   probability that the first five blocks are blue given that last 4
>   blocks are yellow?

If B is the event where the first five blocks are blue, and Y is the event where the last 4 blocks are yellow, I have:

$$
P(B|Y)=\frac{P(B)P(Y|B)}{P(Y)}
$$

Can someone help me out, or is there a different approach to this problem?

**Edit (with solution):**

I should've been looking for:
$$
P(B|Y)=\frac{P(BY)}{P(Y)} = \frac{|BY|}{|Y|}
$$

This gives:

$$
P(B|Y) = \frac{\frac{6!}{3!1!2!}}{\frac{11!}{8!1!2!}} = \frac{8!6!}{11!3!}
$$

Which equals:
$$
\frac{4}{33}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Since the last four blocks are yellow, consider the number of arrangements of $8$ blue, $2$ red, and $1$ yellow blocks.

There are
$$
\frac{11!}{8!\,2!\,1!}\tag{1}
$$
ways to arrange those blocks and only
$$
\frac{6!}{3!2!1!}\tag{2}
$$
where the first $5$ blocks are blue.

Comment: thanks, just updated the question with the solution